# Convert Double to Hex and back to Long in Chinese Unicode for VB6

Tags: vba, unicode, vb6, unicode-string

I am fairly new to VB6 and I would like to convert a parameter from Double to Hex and back to Long for Chinese Unicode.

The issue here is for input values from 1-127, the output is the same. For values beyond 127, the output is 63. The parameter is 4 bytes long. Here's a snippet of the 2 conversion functions I have used so far:

DoubleToHex:

```
Public Function ConvDoubleToHexString(dVal As Double, ByVal nByteCount As Integer) As String
    m = 1
    sHex = Hex(dVal)

    nByteCountMerk = nByteCount
    If nByteCount < Len(sHex) / 2 Then nByteCount = Len(sHex) / 2
    If nByteCount < 1 Then nByteCount = 1

    sHex = String(nByteCount * 2 - Len(sHex), "0") & sHex 
    For n = 0 To nByteCount - 1
        sTmp = ChrW(Val("&H" & Mid(sHex, m, 2)))
        m = m + 2
        sRet = sRet & sTmp
    next n

    If Not bLH Then
        ConvDoubleToHexString = Right(sRet, nByteCountMerk)
    Else
        For n = Len(sRet) To 1 Step -1
            sLH = sLH & Mid(sRet, n, 1)
        Next n
        ConvDoubleToHexString = Left(sLH, nByteCountMerk)
    End If
End Function
```

HexToLong:

```
Public Function ConvHexStringToLong(sHex As String) As Long
    If sHex = "" Then
        ConvHexStringToLongAbs = knolong
        Exit Function
    End If

    For i = 1 To Len(sHex)
        If l >= 8388608 Then
            ConvHexStringToLongAbs = knolong
            Exit Function
        End If

        l = l * 256 * 2
        l = l + Asc(Mid(sHex, i, 1))
    Next

    ConvHexStringToLong = l
End Function
```

Comment: I'm confused why there is a double involved?  That is the wrong datatype to be using for passing any kind of character, no matter the encoding.  Can you please provide addition detail on that parameter?

Comment: Hi @tcarvin thanks for the response. The input parameter works fine for values between 1-127. Beyond that, it shows a '?' as its value which is 63 in Decimal. I'm unable to see the actual values(128+) after conversion. The line which is bugging me is:

    `sTmp = ChrW(Val("&H" & Mid(sHex, m, 2)))`

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just showing you a ? because the debugger or immediate window cannot render those characters in the font they use?

Comment: @tcarvin This is what I see while debugging at each step of the For loop in the DoubleToHex function: 

1. dVal -> 129#  
sHex -> "00000081"  
sTmp -> vbNullChar  
sRet -> vbNullChar  

2. dVal -> 129#  
sHex -> "00000081"  
sTmp -> vbNullChar  
sRet -> String(2,0)  

3. dVal -> 129#  
sHex -> "00000081"  
sTmp -> "?"  
sRet -> String(3,0)  


4. dVal -> 129#  
sHex -> "00000081"  
sTmp -> "?"  
sRet -> String(3,0) & "?"

Answer (score 0):

Moved from comments to answer, there was too much dialog there for SO.

Try changing this:

```
sHex = String(nByteCount * 2 - Len(sHex), "0") & sHex 
For n = 0 To nByteCount - 1
    sTmp = ChrW(Val("&H" & Mid(sHex, m, 2)))
    m = m + 2
    sRet = sRet & sTmp
next n
```

To this:

```
Dim charCode As Long
sHex = String(nByteCount * 2 - Len(sHex), "0") & sHex 
For n = 0 To nByteCount - 1
    sTmp = ChrW(Val("&H" & Mid(sHex, m, 2)))
    charCode = AscW(sTmp)
    m = m + 2
    sRet = sRet & sTmp
next n
```

Then, as you are stepping through the code on each loop in the debugger, confirm that the value of charCode is what you expect it to be.

---

**EDIT:**

I'm still not clear on what you are really trying to accomplish (functions out of context don't tell the story).  But if you are trying to take a unicode string and encode it one character at a time into into Hex then you are going to want to use a 4-character hex code since they are 2 bytes each.  Something like this (not syntax checked):

```
Dim unicodeInput As String 
unicodeInput = "whatever"

Dim offset As Long
Dim charCode As Integer
Dim hexOutput As String

for offset = 1 to Len(unicodeInput)
   charCode = AscW(Mid$(unicodeInput, offset, 1))
   hexOutput = hexOutput & Right$("0000" & Hex$(charCode), 4)
next
```

You can then move that back from hex to the original string doing something like this:

```
Dim hexInput As String 
hexInput = "003900390039"

Dim offset As Long
Dim char As String
Dim output As String

for offset = 1 to Len(hexInput) Step 4
   char = ChrW(CLng("&H" & Mid$(hexInput, offset, 4)))
   output = output & char
next
```

I'm not sure if this solves your problem though because I cannot see why you would want to encode and decode a sequence of unicode characters into a hex buffer.

And you may not want the extra zeros in the hex values, but to accommodate Unicode characters you will need them since they can be larger than a byte.

Comment: the value of charCode is indeed what I expect it to be but then the conversion from Double to Hex isn't happening.

Comment: To be really clear, you are not converting a double to hex.  VB is casting your double to an integer type implicitly.  If you changed you method definition to a Long instead of Double your code would still be the same.  Secondly, I'm not clear on what more you need in a number-to-hex conversion that a simple call to Hex(num) wont solve all by itself.  Can you edit your question to clarify the *objective* or *goal* you are really trying to achieve?

Comment: I actually solved a bit of the question I posted. The issue was, while reading hex values, it was being read as ine(for ex: 999 was being read as 3E7 while I wanted it to be read seperately as shown in the code below (http://imgur.com/B6OE7gG)

Comment: And then, from the ConvToHex fucntion, I have ConvToHex value as String(3,0) & "575757" which is right. As 57 in Dec is 39 in hex which is 9, hence equal to 999. Now the issue is, when I run the code below, I don't get the output 999. What changes should I make in the following code? http://imgur.com/kaG7Rq6